# Mapping memory on custom HW

Tags: c++, linux, memory, mmap

I am new to using mmap and mapping HW registers, maybe the questions are simple. So, my problem is that we have some custom HW, which has 32bit registers. One requirement is that I must use mmap to ensure fast IO operations.

I see in examples that people use dev/mem as a general file. Is this a good idea or should I create my own dev/custom and put the mapped memory in there? Are there any benefits in doing that?

Secondly, are there any tools to let me create a mapped file, like dev/custom or how does one go about doing that?

Thirdly, how do I ensure that the offset is always a multiple of the page size? In my case that is 4096 bytes.

I am using c++ and Linux.

Comment: It is better to crrate `/dev/custom` because your user programs should not know physical addresses of the device, and because it this way is easier to control who can access the device. E.g. you can give non-root users permission to use the device, or restrict number of simultaneous users.

Comment: Btw are you writing the driver in C++?

Comment: Yes, I am using C++, Linux and ARMv7

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your hardware platform. For intel PC you may do either port IO and memory mapped IO, for ARM you do memory IO.

The you should first state that what bus and configuration you support, for example, can it be enumerated with PCI, USB, or just hard-coded communications at special memory (SoC-way)?

The last thing to worry is how to actually map that device (physical) memory into your application or driver's address space. On linux you do mmap with the offset as your hardware's BAR (page-aligned), you may then access the memory mapped IO with the virtual address pointer. (You may need to further adjust the cache flags)

Comment: I understand it will be just hard-coded memory.  I am using ARMv7.

Comment: then just mmap that address, and disable read/write cache, which is processor dependent and I'm not sure on ARM